# ็Exit the test in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I want to exit test in the test case. And do not want the report to show the number of test cases (TC003) that exit test In the example below,

```
*** test cases ***
TC001
    Run Keyword If    '1'=='1'    Log To Console    xx
TC002
    Run Keyword If    '2'=='2'    Log To Console    xx
TC003
    Run Keyword If    '3'!='3'    Exit Test
```

[image]

How do I use it? You can guide me

Comment: What do you mean by "exit"? Do you want to skip execution and do not want to see the test in the log.html in that case?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything you can do. Once the test starts running, there's no way to remove it from the reports and logs.

It sounds like you're trying to skip a test under certain circumstances. If so, it will be able to mark a test as skipped (versus pass/fail) in robot framework 4.0, though it will still show up in the logs and reports.

If you really don't want it in the reports, you can write a script that removes the tests from the output.xml file and then regenerates the html logs and reports using rebot.